# Convert data into chart in HTML using Chart.js without PHP

Tags: html, node.js, chart.js

I have a Node.js server.

In `app.js`, I am sending data from a SQL database to a second page like this:

```
app.get('/yillik',(req, res) => {
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM results`;

    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {

        if (err) throw err;

        res.render('user_resultChart', {
            title: 'RAPORLAMA',
            users: rows
        });

    });

});
```

I process the response in the second page like this:

```
<tbody>
    <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
        <tr>
            <th><%= user.result0 %></th>
            <td><%= user.result1 %></td>
            <td><%= user.result2 %></td>                
            <td><%= user.result3 %></td>
        </tr>
    <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

How can I convert it to a chart with Chart.js. I want to use HTML, not PHP.

Thank you.